# Trying to build a network from the data I collected but facing issues

Tags: python, networkx, tweepy

Trying to access the edge using the source user_id and the target user_id

```
# so we can access the edge using the source user_id and the target user_id
G.edges([nodelist[0]][list(e.keys())[0]])
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-12593dd17b79> in <module>
      1 # so we can access the edge using the source user_id and the target user_id
----> 2 G.edges([nodelist[0]][list(e.keys())[0]])

AttributeError: 'OutEdgeDataView' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

**Another error I am facing...**

Trying to list all nodes

```
# listing all nodes 
nodelist = G.nodes()
nodelist[:3]
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-0135a95aa2ab> in <module>
      1 # listing all nodes
      2 nodelist = G.nodes()
----> 3 nodelist[:3]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\reportviews.py in __getitem__(self, n)
    176 
    177     def __getitem__(self, n):
--> 178         return self._nodes[n]
    179 
    180     # Set methods

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your errors are related. I'm not sure because you don't define the variable `e` in the code above, but based on the type in the error it looks like you defined it as `e = G.edges()` which returns an `OutEdgeDataView` object rather than a dict as you desire. You can get a list of the graph edges using `e = list(G.edges())` which gives you a list of tuples where the first item of the tuple is the source node and the second item is the target node. Then to get the edge attributes for the edge corresponding to `nodelist[0]` you can say `G.edge[nodelist[0],the_tail_node]`.

For your second error, G.nodes() is not a list and doesn't support slicing. When you define `nodelist` above you can do `nodelist = list(G.nodes())` and then you can slice as desired.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you. I shall ruminate on this a bit.